# Prove the inequality of area of convex polygon X is A is less than or equal to $\frac{\pi d^2}{ 4}$

Tags: geometry

I want to prove that convex polygon X in the plane has diameter d, its area is less than or equal to  $\frac{\pi d^2}{ 4}$.

Comment: What is $x$ in your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show that $X$ is contained in a circle of diameter $d$?

Comment: @crostul, I don't know how to prove

Comment: @crostul , X is convex polygon

Comment: The hypothesis that $X$ is convex is useless: this is true even for non-convex polygons (the convex hull of any polygon is a convex polygon with the same diameter).

Comment: @ crostul, do you have idea to prove it ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we can assume it to be convex and then prove it this inequality

Comment: @ crodtul, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This known as the isodiametric inequality. If you can cope with a little calculus the simplest proof is that in Littlewood's Miscellany.

Take the figure in the upper half plane and describe it by polar coordinates $r=f(\theta)$. The area is $$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi}f(\theta)^2\ d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\theta)^2+f(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})^2\ d\theta$$.

But the integrand is the square of the distance between two points of the figure, so it cannot exceed $d^2$. So $A\le\pi\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2$.

[image]